# Function call not printing 2D array representation

Tags: c, arrays

I'm implementing a sliding puzzle program in C based on what the user inputs as their width of the slide (can only be 2, 3, 4). I feel like my syntax is correct for creating the 2D array (which is what we are using to represent the numbers in a later function), however, my function is not being called correctly. Instead it is hanging when I try to run it.

I cannot change the syntax of the function because it is a requirement that we have this in our program. So I'm wondering if it is a program passing in the function in main. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
int main() {                                                                    
int w; /*variable asking for width*/                                            

 printf("Width: ");                                                          
 scanf("%d\n", &w); /*&w will refer to make_tiles when function is called*/  
  make_tiles(w);                                                              
  return 0;                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                            
int **make_tiles(int width) {                                                    
int **tiles;                                                                    
int counter = 0;                                                                
int i, j;                                                                       
tiles[i] = (int*) malloc(width*sizeof(int*));                               
for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {                                                    
for(j = 1; j < width; j++) {                                                
tiles[i][j] = counter++;                                                    
printf(" %d", tiles[i][j]);                                                       
}                                                                          
printf("\n");                                                               
}                                                                            
}
```

Comment: change `scanf("%d\n", &w);` to `scanf("%d", &w);`

Comment: `make_tiles()` has multiple counts of undefined behaviour in the statement `tiles[i] = (int *)malloc(width * sizeof (int *))` since (1)  `tiles` itself is uninitialised  (2)  the `(int *)` conversion forces the code to compile, even though there is no `#include <stdlib>`.   It doesn't help that the AMOUNT of memory being allocated is also incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior here. You have forget to allocate memory in `tiles[i]`. Also `i` is unintilized. Accessing an memory not allocated is also undefined behaviour.

```
int **tiles;                                                                    
int counter = 0;                                                                

tiles  = malloc(width*sizeof*tiles); 
if( tiles == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
    exit(1);
}                              
for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  tiles[i] = malloc(sizeof *tiles[i] * width);
  if( tiles[i] == NULL){
     fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
     exit(1);
  }

}
```

You didn't return anything from the method. Also you should free the allocated memory.

If you notice this code you will see that I haven't cast the return value of `malloc` because this is unnecessary. Also it as mentioned in comment if you forget to include `stdlib.h` header. (Because prior to C11 undeclared functions are considered to return `int` which if differently size than an `int*` cause an erroneous result).

Example code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int** make_tiles(int w);

int main() {
    int w; /*variable asking for width*/                                            

    printf("Width: ");                                                          
    if( scanf("%d", &w) != 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in input");
        exit(1);
    }

    int **arr = make_tiles(w);  
    // you can work with arr here.   

    for(size_t i = 0; i < w ; i++)
        free(arr[i]);  
    free(arr);                                                       
    return 0;                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                        
int **make_tiles(int width) {                                                    
    int **tiles;                                                                    
    int counter = 0;                                                                

    if( width <= 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error : Specify correct width [>=0]");
        exit(1);
    }
    tiles  = malloc(width*sizeof*tiles); 
    if( tiles == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
        exit(1);
    }                              
    for(size_t i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      tiles[i] = malloc(sizeof *tiles[i] * width);
      if( tiles[i] == NULL){
         fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
         exit(1);
      }
    }  
    for(size_t i = 0; i < width ; i++){
        for(size_t j = 0; j < width ;  j++){
            tiles[i][j] = counter++;
            printf("%4d ", tiles[i][j]);

        }
        printf("%s","\n");
    }     
    return tiles;                                              
}
```